# React Hooks: Value of Input component (Semantic-ui-react) doesn't change after re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am facing an issue with input component. Initially I get data from API and assign it to a variable (htmlTableData) with useState() hook. Next the value prop of input component is set to the variable (The variable htmlTableDatum.value is null ). Next I enter some value in input field (Ex: 123). Later I again get the same data from API and again assign it to a variable (htmlTableData) with useState() hook. Again the value prop of input component is set to the variable (The variable htmlTableDatum.value is still null as I haven't saved 123 to database. I even console logged the htmlTableDatum.value. htmlTableDatum.value is still null). But the value in input component is still 123. I am not sure what is the issue.(Please Note: I do not wish to force render. I can do that by setting setHtmlTableData([]). But I hope that there is another way)[image]

```
<Table basic='very' celled collapsing>
    <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Value</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Status</Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
    </Table.Header>

    <Table.Body>
    {htmlTableData.map((htmlTableDatum) => (
        <Table.Row>
        <Table.Cell>{htmlTableDatum.name}</Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell><Input value={htmlTableDatum.value} onChange={(e) => setFieldValue(e, htmlTableDatum.name)} /></Table.Cell>
        <Table.Cell textAlign='center'>
            {htmlTableDatum.isValid & htmlTableDatum.isSaved ? <Label circular color='green' empty/> : null}
            {htmlTableDatum.isValid & htmlTableDatum.isSaved == false ? <Label circular color='violet' empty/> : null}
            {htmlTableDatum.isValid == false ? <Label circular color='orange' empty/> : null}
        </Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
    ))}
    </Table.Body>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 1):

After much effort, I finally found the issue.

The issue is that one should never initialize the 'value' prop of an Input component with 'null' value. (i.e. `<Input value={null} />`)

If we get data from API and the value to be assigned to Input component is null, then one could do some thing like this (i.e. initialize with empty string):

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

fetch('/getInputValue').then(response => response.json()).then((data) => setInputValue(data.value == null? '': data.value))

render(
   <Input value={inputValue} />
)
```